# Can you give a tip how to create a video with such effect?

Tags: video, after-effects, video-editor, camera, effects

I really like these effects and I would like to reproduce it.

I would like to point that I don't know how this effect is called. Whether it is made within a camera or in post production?

Here is 2 videos that have this. They are not identical but I think they are quite similar. I like how the video has some kind of distortion.

In the first video it is like fast forward with a lot of camera movement. You can see it starting from here

In the second video it is like fast forward but is slow motion. The effect can be seen when the drummer is in a frame.

So my questions are:

1. If it is in camera effect how is it made?
2. How to achieve it in video editing software?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a so called hyperlapse. Just not a smooth one. It is basically just speed up.

Same goes for the second one, just that it also has a diffrent shutter speed.

So how to do them:

Simply record the walking video and speed it up in post.

To achieve the special look in the second one, not every camera can do that. You need a camera with a really low FPS, for example 10, then you also expose 1/10 second. You should get a similair look, then you will need to experiment. But that effect may be hard to achieve on a digital/cheaper camera.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It really helped. Here is an another example. youtu.be/XmSdTa9kaiQ?t=46 . Basically I want to achieve this effect. It seems like it is slow frame rate but lip sync is not slow here. That is interesting. You can see the effect through the whole video.

Comment: @KirillRyzhkov I guess they shot it at 18 FPS with an analog camera. Also it is just slowly moving, but no slow motion I'd guess

Comment: all right, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The lower clip looks like it was shot on film, with a slow shutter speed and slow frame rate, to get lots of motion blur within each frame.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It really helped. Here is an another example. youtu.be/XmSdTa9kaiQ?t=46 . Basically I want to achieve this effect. It seems like it is slow frame rate but lip sync is not slow here. That is interesting. You can see the effect through the whole video.